# How constructor and destructor called during template object in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

Can you please explain how constructor and destructor is called,
Because when i see the output for tempravary object 4 destructor called more times

output
item Args constructor called 1
1 100
item Args constructor called 2
2 Proffecessor
item Args constructor called 4
item Args constructor called 3
item desconstructor called 4
3 4 Professor
item desconstructor called 4
item desconstructor called 4
item desconstructor called 3
item desconstructor called 4
item desconstructor called 2
item desconstructor called 1

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template <typename template_type>
class item
{
    string name;
    template_type value;
    public:
        item(string name, template_type value)
        :name{name}, value{value}
        {
            cout<<"item Args constructor called "<<name<<endl;
        }
        ~item()
        {
            cout<<"item desconstructor called "<<name<<endl;
        }
        string get_name()const
        {
            return name;
        }
        template_type get_value()const
        {
            return value;
        }
};


int main()
{

    item<int> item1{"1", 100 };
    cout<<item1.get_name()<<" "<<item1.get_value()<<endl;

    item<string> item2{"2", "Proffecessor" };
    cout<<item2.get_name()<<" "<<item2.get_value()<<endl;

    item<item<string>>  item3{"3", {"4","Professor"}};
    cout<<item3.get_name()<<" "
        <<item3.get_value().get_name()<<" "
        <<item3.get_value().get_value()<<endl;

}
```

Comment: you miss the copy constructor (rule of 3/5/0)

Comment: Your `get_value()` method return a *copy* of the `value` member; so the multiple 4 destruction; you can try returning a reference to avoid this problem.

Comment: You should print the value of `this` in your destructors, not just a simple message.  You will see that the destructors are being called on different objects.  That would also indicate you are not tracking all of the different constructors that occur, like the copy constructor.

Comment: @max66 i got it why extra copy constructor is calling. When i changed to return the reference from get_value() no copy made again.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, printed this in both constructor and destructors. I got when destructor called for each constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the copy constructor. That's why you see more destructor call than constructor. You can also see it with this code.

---

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template <typename template_type>
class item
{
    string name;
    template_type value;
    
    public:
    item(string name, template_type value):name{name}, value{value}
    {
        cout<<"item Args constructor called "<<name<<endl;
    }
    /* you miss the copy constructor
    item(const item&)
    {
        cout<<"item copy" <<endl;
    }
    */
    ~item()
    {
        cout<<"item desconstructor called "<<name<<endl;
    }
};

void foo(item<int> i){}

int main()
{
    item<int> item1{"1", 100 };
    foo(item1);
}
```

output

```
item Args constructor called 1
item desconstructor called 1
item desconstructor called 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xhWh9hGr6

Comment: I would suggest printing `this` in the destructor message.  I believe that would get the point across immediately as to what's going on.

Comment: @apple apple Yes, i forgot the copy constructor, Now i completely understood.